# how to upload image metadata to mysql column

Tags: php, html, mysql

[this is the jpeg file im trying to upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRaQk.jpg)I have a PHP code that uploads images to MySql DB, I was trying to figure how I can add a column with metadata like GPS, camera type, day/night, etc.. what i need to do is add a metadata columns and search a specific metadata from all images.
I have the following PHP code:
`

```
    <?php 
    // Include the database configuration file 
    include_once 'dbconfig.php'; 
     
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
       // File upload configuration 
       $targetDir = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\uploaded\\"; 
       $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif'); 
     
       $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = ''; 
       $fileNames = array_filter($_FILES['files']['name']); 
       if(!empty($fileNames)){ 
           function getExif( $filename, $key1, $key2)
    {
    $width = 0;
    $allowedFiletypes = array("jpg","jpeg","tif","tiff");
    if(in_array(strtolower(substr($filename, -3)),$allowedFiletypes))
    {
    if(exif_read_data($filename) == true) //this is line 19
    {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);

    foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        if($key === $key1 AND $name === $key2){
        $width = $val;
    }
    }
    }
    }
    return $width;
    }
    else
    {
    print "filetype not supported";
    }
    }

    $key1 = "IFD0";
    $key2 = "ImageWidth";

    foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){ 
    // File upload path 
    $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]); 
    $width = getExif( $fileName, $key1, $key2);
    
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName; 
     // Check whether file type is valid 
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 
    // Upload file to server 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){ 
        // Image db insert sql 
        $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW(), '".$width."'),"; 
     }else{ 
                   $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
               } 
           }else{ 
               $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
           } 
       } 
       // Error message 
       $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.trim($errorUpload, ' | '):''; 
       $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.trim($errorUploadType, '    | '):''; 
       $errorMsg =      !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType; 
     
       if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){ 
           $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL, ','); 
           // Insert image file name into database 
           $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images(file_name, uploaded_on, image_width) VALUES      $insertValuesSQL"); 
            if($insert){ 
                $statusMsg = "Files are uploaded successfully.".$errorMsg; 
            }else{ 
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $statusMsg = "Upload failed! ".$errorMsg; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.'; 
       } 
   } 
 
   ?>
   <form action="upload1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       Select Image Files to Upload:
       <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple >
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD">
   </form>
```

`

how can I get the image metadata while uploading the image

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this? [Start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+get+image+metadata).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exif extension of php. Activate it and the mbstring extension too. With the following code snippet you have access to an array with all information you need.

Beneath there is an example for ["IFD0"]["ImageWidth"]. The value is written in the variable $width for each image which is uploaded.

Then I extended the definition of the variable $insertValuesSQL and the insert statement with the "width" varible. In this case the value is written in the column "image_with" of your table "images".

In addition the function "getExif()" was added for missing or incomplete exif information:

```
<?php
function getExif( $filename, $key1, $key2)
{
$width = 0;
$allowedFiletypes = array("jpg","jpeg","tif","tiff");
$ext = explode('.', $filename);
if(in_array(strtolower($ext[1]),$allowedFiletypes))
{
if(exif_read_data($filename) == true)
{
$exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);

foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        if($key === $key1 AND $name === $key2){
        $width = $val;
    }
    }
}
}
return $width;
}
else
{
print "filetype not supported";
}
}

$key1 = "IFD0";
$key2 = "ImageWidth";

foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $key=>$val){ 
    // File upload path 
    $fileName = basename($_FILES['files']['name'][$key]); 
    $width = getExif( $fileName, $key1, $key2);
    
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName; 
     // Check whether file type is valid 
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){ 
    // Upload file to server 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], $targetFilePath)){ 
        // Image db insert sql 
        $insertValuesSQL .= "('".$fileName."', NOW(), '".$width."'),"; 
     }else{ 
                   $errorUpload .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
               } 
           }else{ 
               $errorUploadType .= $_FILES['files']['name'][$key].' | '; 
           } 
       } 
       // Error message 
       $errorUpload = !empty($errorUpload)?'Upload Error: '.trim($errorUpload, ' | '):''; 
       $errorUploadType = !empty($errorUploadType)?'File Type Error: '.trim($errorUploadType, '    | '):''; 
       $errorMsg =      !empty($errorUpload)?'<br/>'.$errorUpload.'<br/>'.$errorUploadType:'<br/>'.$errorUploadType; 
     
       if(!empty($insertValuesSQL)){ 
           $insertValuesSQL = trim($insertValuesSQL, ','); 
           // Insert image file name into database 
           $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images(file_name, uploaded_on, image_width) VALUES      $insertValuesSQL"); 
....
?>
```

Comment: ok, but I was trying to upload multiple images and i want all the images to appear in mysql with their metadata, i mean that i uploaded images will be with their meta data

Comment: I updated the answer with an example for the exif value ["IFD0"]["ImageWidth"].

Comment: thank you for your answer. but when i run this it uploads the images i picked and it have value 0 on image width. also i am getting an error:  Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploaded.php on line 16

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploaded.php on line 17

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\uploaded.php on line 17

Comment: @rauwitt It would be best to read the metadata _after_ moving the file to its permanent location IMO. But if you want to read it before that, the file is stored in `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key]`, not in the one you've used here. At https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php you can remind yourself what all the fields contain.

Comment: @Tom Meskin: This error occurs if the image file format is not supported or its exif metadata is not complete. For this cases I inserted a function "getExif()" which uses the exif keys as parameter.

Comment: @rauwitt ok i added the code now, and it print that file type not supported. my files are all jpeg what does it means that it is not supported?

Comment: @Tom Meskin: Could you upload your jpeg files again?

Comment: @rauwitt i edited the question and uploaded the jpeg file in the question. when i try to upload the image to mysql it uploads but i have the error that the file is not supported and i have 0 in the image width column

Comment: @rauwitt you still haven't fixed the bug I pointed out yesterday. Until you do that, none of this will work as designed.

Comment: @ADyson: I changed the definition of $fileName in the foreach loop as you said but then I got no exif data. With $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key] it works for me.

Comment: @Tom Meskin: Are you sure that the uploaded  jpeg files contain exif data? Images from mobile devices always have some.

Comment: @Tom Meskin: The image at the beginning of your question contains no exif data.

Comment: @rauwitt i found an image that contains exif data and when i try to upload it, it uploads with now image width and it throws an error:  "Warning: exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload1.php on line 19" also i updated the code at the question for you to see the line 19.